# Filtering pandas dataframe rows by contains str

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a python pandas dataframe `df` with a lot of rows.  From those rows, I want to slice out and only use the rows that contain the word 'ball' in the 'body' column.  To do that, I can do:

`df[df['body'].str.contains('ball')]`

The issue is, I want it to be case insensitive, meaning that if the word Ball or bAll showed up, I'll want those as well.  One way to do case insensitive search is to turn the string to lowercase and then search that way.  I'm wondering how to go about doing that. I tried

`df[df['body'].str.lower().contains('ball')]`

But that doesn't work.  I'm not sure if I'm supposed to use a lambda function on this or something of that nature.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You could either use `.str` again to get access to the string methods, or (better, IMHO) use `case=False` to guarantee case insensitivity:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"body": ["ball", "red BALL", "round sphere"]})
>>> df[df["body"].str.contains("ball")]
   body
0  ball
>>> df[df["body"].str.lower().str.contains("ball")]
       body
0      ball
1  red BALL
>>> df[df["body"].str.contains("ball", case=False)]
       body
0      ball
1  red BALL
>>> df[df["body"].str.contains("ball", case=True)]
   body
0  ball
```

(Note that if you're going to be doing assignments, it's a better habit to use `df.loc`, to avoid the dreaded SettingWithCopyWarning, but if we're just selecting here it doesn't matter.)

(Note #2: guess I really didn't need to specify 'round' there..)

Comment: Amazing.  I was close to chaining `str` events.  I didn't know `str.contains` has a `case=False` option.  That's great.  One more follow up: I've gotten the dreaded SettingWithCopy Warning that you referred to.  Would you mind elaborating on it a little?  My goal is to create a new dataframe of just the rows that contain 'ball'

Comment: That's a bit too long of a story to write here in the comments.  You can read [this section](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html?highlight=settingwithcopywarning#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) of the documentation for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How can I add multiple strings for the filtering?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) inside [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query):

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'body': ['Ball', 'cUbE', 'bAll'], 'color': ['red', 'green', 'blue']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
   body  color
0  Ball    red
1  cUbE  green
2  bAll   blue

In [4]: df.query('body.str.contains("ball", case=False).values')
Out[4]: 
   body color
0  Ball   red
2  bAll  blue
```

If you try to match multiple patterns use `|`:

```
In [5]: df.query('body.str.contains("ball|cube", case=False).values')
Out[5]: 
   body  color
0  Ball    red
1  cUbE  green
2  bAll   blue
```