# pandas dataframe search string in the entire row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, search

I have a pandas dataframe like below. I want to search a text in each row of the dataframe and highlight if that text appears in the row.

For example, I want to search each row for "jones". I want to ignore the case of my search word. In the below case, I would like to add a new column to data called "jones" and it would have values 1,1,0 as that word was found in 1st and 2nd row

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616261/filtering-pandas-dataframe-rows-by-contains-str) post which shows how to find a text in a column, but how could I find a text when I have many columns - say 50+? I thought about concatenating all the columns and creating a new column, but didn't see any function that would concatenate all columns of a dataframe (without asking to type each column name)

I would like to do this for multiple keywords that I have. For example I have list of keyword `LLC, Co, Blue, alpha` and many more (30+)

```
sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': '150', 'Feb': '200', 'Mar': '140'},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '210', 'Mar': '215'},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': '50',  'Feb': '90',  'Mar': '95' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
```

Source DF:

```
   Feb    Jan  Mar    account
0  200    150  140  Jones LLC
1  210  Jones  215   Alpha Co
2   90     50   95   Blue Inc
```

Desired DF:

```
   Feb    Jan  Mar    account  jones  llc  co  blue  alpha
0  200    150  140  Jones LLC      1    1   0     0      0
1  210  Jones  215   Alpha Co      1    0   1     0      1
2   90     50   95   Blue Inc      0    0   0     1      0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we use pandas built-in `str` function `contains`, along with `apply` and then bring it all together with `any` as follows,

```
search_string = 'Jones'

df[search_string] = (df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search_string))
                       .any(axis=1).astype(int))
df

Out[2]:
     Feb    Jan    Mar   account     Jones
0    200    150    140   Jones LLC   1
1    210    Jones  215   Alpha Co    1
2    90     50     95    Blue Inc    0
```

This can be easily extended as `contains` uses regular expressions to do the matching. It also has a case arg so that you can make it case-insensitive and search for both `Jones` and `jones`.

In order to loop over a list of search words we need to make the following changes. By storing each search result (a `Series`) in a list, we use the list to join the series together in to `DataFrame`. We do this because we don't want to search new columns for the new search_string,

```
df_list = []

for search_string in ['Jones', 'Co', 'Alpha']:
    #use above method but rename the series instead of setting to
    # a columns. The append to a list.
    df_list.append(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search_string))
                     .any(axis=1)
                     .astype(int)
                     .rename(search_string))

#concatenate the list of series into a DataFrame with the original df
df = pd.concat([df] + df_list, axis=1)
df

Out[5]:
    Feb    Jan     Mar    account    Jones  Co   Alpha
0   200    150     140    Jones LLC  1      0    0
1   210    Jones   215    Alpha Co   1      1    1
2   90     50      95     Blue Inc   0      0    0
```

Comment: if I have multiple search strings, how could I search them one at a time and add additional columns? For example I want to search for LLC, Co, Blue, alpha etc and I want a new column for each keyword

Comment: @Ni_Tempe is this relatively small list? If so, just repeat the above n times. Otherwise I think it is a for-loop over that above...

Comment: Ho do you take care of case? The problem with that approach 9writing for loop for additional keywords) is when I search for the second keyword onwards, python would search for recently created columns for the keyword too...I am going to have have 30+ keywords

Comment: @MaxU - you are welcome to keep it there :) I can see that it was a very concise addition!

Comment: @josh, sorry, it went to my answer already, but here is my ++ as an excuse... ;-)

Comment: could you briefly explain your code so that readers could learn and use it in future?

Comment: @Ni_Tempe I have added code comments and enhanced the description

Comment: would it be possible to show how to get count of matches instead of 1 or 0?

Comment: I looked into python help and tried to use `x.str.count`, but id didn't provide a count :(, I would appreciate if you could help

Comment: Use `sum` in place of `any`.

Comment: I tried `sum`, but it didn't give expected results :(

Comment: I posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346183/python-count-how-many-times-a-string-is-present-in-the-entire-row-of-a-pandas-da

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** you seem to want OneHotEncode some specific words - you can use [sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) for that:

```
In [131]: from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

In [132]: vocab = ['jones', 'llc', 'co', 'blue', 'alpha']

In [133]: cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)

In [134]: r = pd.SparseDataFrame((cv.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes('object').add(' ').sum(1)) != 0) * 1,
                                 df.index, 
                                 cv.get_feature_names(), 
                                 default_fill_value=0)

In [135]: r
Out[135]:
   jones  llc  co  blue  alpha
0      1    1   0     0      0
1      1    0   1     0      1
2      0    0   0     1      0
```

you can also merge it with your original DF:

```
In [137]: df = df.join(r)

In [138]: df
Out[138]:
   Feb    Jan  Mar    account  jones  llc  co  blue  alpha
0  200    150  140  Jones LLC      1    1   0     0      0
1  210  Jones  215   Alpha Co      1    0   1     0      1
2   90     50   95   Blue Inc      0    0   0     1      0
```

**Explanation:**

concatenate all string columns into a single one, using space as a separator:

```
In [165]: df.select_dtypes('object').add(' ').sum(1)
Out[165]:
0    200 150 140 Jones LLC LLC
1       210 Jones 215 Alpha Co
2            90 50 95 Blue Inc
dtype: object
```

generate a One Hot Encode sparse matrix with selected features:

```
In [176]: A = (cv.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes('object').add(' ').sum(1)) != 0) * 1

In [177]: A
Out[177]:
<3x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int32'>'
        with 6 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>

In [178]: A.A
Out[178]:
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])

In [179]: cv.get_feature_names()
Out[179]: ['jones', 'llc', 'co', 'blue', 'alpha']
```

generate a SparseDataFrame out of it:

```
In [174]: r = pd.SparseDataFrame((cv.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes('object').add(' ').sum(1)) != 0) * 1,
     ...:                        df.index,
     ...:                        cv.get_feature_names(),
     ...:                        default_fill_value=0)
     ...:
     ...:

In [175]: r
Out[175]:
   jones  llc  co  blue  alpha
0      1    1   0     0      0
1      1    0   1     0      1
2      0    0   0     1      0
```

Comment: if I have multiple search strings, how could I search them one at a time and add additional columns? For example I want to search for LLC, Co, Blue, alpha etc and I want a new column for each keyword

Comment: @Ni_Tempe it might be best adding this to your question.

Comment: I have it already. It is the last line of my question. I appreciate your help

Comment: Yes, I see it now! - it might also be worth adding your example from the comment `LLC, Co, Blue, alpha`

Comment: In case of the new solution, could i get count of matches instead of 1 or 0? also could you briefly explain your code so that readers could learn and use it in future?

Comment: thanks for adding explanation...could you show how to get counts of matches instead of 1 and 0?

Comment: @Ni_Tempe, `cv.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes('object').add(' ').sum(1)` instead of `(cv.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes('object').add(' ').sum(1)) != 0) * 1` - will give you counts

Comment: yes. I tried your original answer and I get an error `File "<ipython-input-7-62c147717ca4>", line 11, in <module>
    r = pd.SparseDataFrame((cv.fit_transform(df.select_dtypes('object').add(' ').sum(1)) != 0) * 1,df.index, cv.get_feature_names(), default_fill_value=` `TypeError: include and exclude must both be non-string sequences`