# python count how many times a string is present in the entire row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a question based upon my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330608/pandas-dataframe-search-sting-in-the-entire-row). Below code runs fine and it tells me whether the `search_string` is present in the entire row or not. How could I modify the last line so that it provides me counts of matches instead of 1 or 0? For example, for the first row it should return 4 as my `search_string` is present in 4 locations in that row.

```
sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC jones', 'Jan': '150', 'Feb': '200', 'Mar': '140 jones jones'},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '210', 'Mar': '215'},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': '50',  'Feb': '90',  'Mar': '95' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df

search_string = 'Jones'

(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search_string))
                       .sum(axis=1).astype(int))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findall` and `.str.len`:

```
sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC jones', 'Jan': '150', 'Feb': '200', 'Mar': '140 jones jones'},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '210', 'Mar': '215'},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': '50',  'Feb': '90',  'Mar': '95' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df

search_string = 'jones' #Note changed to lowercase j to find more data.

(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.findall(search_string).str.len())
                       .sum(axis=1).astype(int))
```

Output:

```
0    3
1    0
2    0
dtype: int32
```

---

Add @Vaishali edit to solution:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().str.findall(search_string).str.len()).sum(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0    4
1    1
2    0
dtype: int32
```

Comment: why didn't it return 1 on the second row? 2nd row of the 2nd column has Jones

Comment: @Ni_Tempe See updat with Vaishali modification

Answer (score 1):

Using the code from the previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48330608/pandas-dataframe-search-sting-in-the-entire-row), we simple change the `any` method to a `sum` method. The adds up all of the 1's to effectively count the number of occurrences in a gives row (axis=1).

```
## added and extra Jones into row 1 for 'Jan' column
sales = [{'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '200', 'Mar': '140'},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '210', 'Mar': '215'},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': '50',  'Feb': '90',  'Mar': '95' }]

df = pd.DataFrame(sales)

df_list = []

for search_string in ['Jones', 'Co', 'Alpha']:
    #use above method but rename the series instead of setting to
    # a columns. The append to a list.
    df_list.append(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search_string))
                     .sum(axis=1) ## HERE IS SUM in place of any
                     .astype(int)
                     .rename(search_string))

#concatenate the list of series into a DataFrame with the original df
df = pd.concat([df] + df_list, axis=1)
df

Out[2]:
    Feb Jan    Mar   account     Jones  Co   Alpha
0   200 Jones  140   Jones LLC   2      0    0
1   210 Jones  215   Alpha Co    1      1    1
2   90  50     95    Blue Inc    0      0    0
```

Comment: I used search string "jones", but it didn't return 4 in the data frame mentioned in this question. Does this search over all columns?

Comment: @Ni_Tempe yes, the `axis=1`  part should ensure that it this is applied row-wise. It could be that you have non-string or object type columns in your actual `DataFrame` and this ignores them. I assume this would have thrown an error though.