# python findall and regex while searching in the entire row

Tags: python, regex, search, find

I have below code that searches for a given words in the entire row. The code is from my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48346183/python-count-how-many-times-a-string-is-present-in-the-entire-row-of-a-pandas-da/48355413#48355413). Currently, python search for occurrence of given words within the row. But I want to find complete words only.

when python searches for 'jo', it shouldn't return any results as there is no word 'jo', but when searching for 'jones' python should return 5 in the first row

1) How should I modify my search? I understand that I have to use regex. But I am not sure how to implement it.
I tried `findall((?i)\bsearch_string\b)`, but got an error

2) Below code gives errors if any column has datatype float. To overcome the problem, I am splitting my original dataframe in non-numeric and numeric columns, running below code and then joining numeric columns back. Is there an elegant way to do the same

```
sales = [{'account': 'jones', 'Jan': '150 jones', 'Feb': '200 jones', 'Mar': '140 jones jones'},
         {'account': '1',  'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '210', 'Mar': '215'},
         {'account': '1',  'Jan': '50',  'Feb': '90',  'Mar': '95' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df

df_list = []

search_string='jones'
for search_string in ['jo', 'jones']:
    #use above method but rename the series instead of setting to
    # a columns. The append to a list.
    df_list.append(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().str.findall(search_string).str.len()).sum(axis=1).astype(int).rename(search_string))

#concatenate the list of series into a DataFrame with the original df
df = pd.concat([df] + df_list, axis=1)
df
```

#

Updated code that uses answer given below

```
sales = [{'account': 'jones.', 'Jan': '150 jones', 'Feb': '200 .jones', 'Mar': '140 jones jones'},
         {'account': '1',  'Jan': 'Jones', 'Feb': '210', 'Mar': '215'},
         {'account': '1',  'Jan': '50',  'Feb': '90',  'Mar': '95' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df

df_list = []

search_string='jones'
for search_string in ['jones.', 'jone','jones']:
    #use above method but rename the series instead of setting to
    # a columns. The append to a list.
    df_list.append(df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower().str.findall(r'\b{0}\b'.format(search_string)).str.len()).sum(axis=1).astype(int).rename(search_string))

#concatenate the list of series into a DataFrame with the original df
df = pd.concat([df] + df_list, axis=1)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to put the search string into a regex to then do a match, this should do that:

```
import re
test_str = ("account"
                "jones"
                "Jan"
                "150 jones"
                "Feb"
                "200 jones"
                "Mar"
                "140 jones jones")

for search_string in ['jo', 'jones']:
    regex = r'\b{0}\b'.format(search_string)
    number_of_matches = len(re.findall(regex, test_str))

    print(number_of_matches)
```

Haven't been able to test with panda, but should give you enough to work with.