# Pandas: Delete a row if a string is contained in any of the multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, delete-row

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
import pandas as pd
   df = pd.DataFrame({'Subject1': ['Math', 'BioScience', 'PhysicalScience',
                                'Sociology', 'Psychology', 'Arts'],
                       'Subject2': ['BioScience', 'PhysicalScience', 'Sociology', 
                                   'Arts', 'Arts', 'PhysicalScience'],
                       'points': [10, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5]})
```

I would like to delete the rows where `Subject1` or `Subject2` column contains the string "Science".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter pandas DataFrame by substring criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350770/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-substring-criteria)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering pandas dataframe rows by contains str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616261/filtering-pandas-dataframe-rows-by-contains-str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it

```
# choose rows where subject1 or subject2 contains 'science'
# negate the result to choose rows that fails the match

out=df.loc[~(df['Subject1'].str.contains('Science') | 
             df['Subject2'].str.contains('Science'))]
out
```

```
Subject1    Subject2    points
3   Sociology   Arts    6
4   Psychology  Arts    6
```